# Win10 registry: difference between Background and shell in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, context-menu

I'm talking about the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT registry keys for Windows 10. Changes to the keys in `background` changes the right click menu when you've clicked inside of a folder. But what do changes to the keys in `shell` do?

(To be clear, I'm talking about the shell directory that is an immediate child of the Directory key, on the same level as the Background key. Of course, both this shell key and the Background key have a subkey also named shell.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands under:
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Shell`

are in the context menu of the folder itself ( right-clicked from parent folder )
[image]

Interestingly, when you right click a file system folder in the Navigation Pane, you see commands fron both:
[image]

Rrember, HKCR is  a virtual hive made up from entries under:
**`HKCU\Software\Classes`**
and
**`HKLM\SoftWare\Classes`**

So, in general, read from `HKCR` but write to `HKCU` or `HKLM`.

Comment: Thank you. So background is the context menu in general, and shell is the context menu only when you right click a folder.

Comment: Yes, except I think of Background as the exception applying only to `Directory` and `Folder`, and `Shell` as the more "general", as it appears under many more types. `Background` in unique to containers.